# Views testing and Devise's current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

It's my first views test.
Not sure if I understand whole mocks/stubs/doubles concept, so probably problem is there.

I'm testing simple Login/Signup | username/Logout links.

application.html.erb:

```
  ...
    <ul>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li>
          <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>        
          <%= current_user.username %>
        </li>
      <% else %>
        <li>
          <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %>  
          <%= link_to('Sign up', new_user_registration_path) %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  ...
```

application.hmtl.erb_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "layouts/application.html.erb" do

  context "when user is signed in" do
    before :each do
      view.stub(:user_signed_in?) { true }

      current_user = double()
      current_user.stub(:username) { "Joe" }
      render
    end

    it "displays logout link" do
      expect(rendered).to have_link 'Logout'
    end

    it "displays username" do
      expect(rendered).to have_content 'Joe'
    end

    ...

  end
end
```

I get an error:

```
 Failure/Error: render
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method 'authenticate' for nil:NilClass
```

in line with `<%= current_user.username %>`

So it looks like this username stub doesn't work, any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: did you try https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec)

Comment: Yes, but it's not working. They they wrote in docs: These helpers are not going to work for integration tests driven by Capybara or Webrat. They are meant to be used with functional tests only. Instead, fill in the form or explicitly set the user in session;

Answer (score 6):

I solved this:

```
  view.stub(:user_signed_in?) { true }
  view.stub(:current_user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, username: "Joe") }
```

Comment: Update for the new Rspec 2.14+ & 3 syntax:  `allow(view).to receive(:user_signed_in?) { true }` and `allow(view).to receive(:current_user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, username 'Joe') }`